# Get all except built-in schema names from a specific database using T-SQL query

Tags: t-sql, schema

As the title entails, is this possible?

Using the following code returns a list of the built-in schemas as well as all the other schemas:

```
select name from MyDbName.sys.schemas
```

What I want is only the schemas I created for each table. I also tried doing the following code but its not very solid.

```
select name from MyDbName.sys.schemas where name not like '%db_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) from sys.objects
```

I think this will work for you.

Comment: The result of that query also includes `sys` and `dbo` schemas, you can exclude it by schema_id.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following:

```
SELECT name
  FROM sys.schemas  
 WHERE schema_id NOT IN (SELECT schema_id FROM model.sys.schemas)
```

This lists all schemas except the ones that are present when a new database is created (by querying the `model` database).